# Show number of items in Django in list view

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to show the number of each category in Leads. But i am unable to show it. Appriciate your help.

I am learning django and python. Tried many opiton, but failed.

Below is my code.

Model:

```
class Leads(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    age = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    orginasation = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    agent = models.ForeignKey("Agent",null=True, blank= True ,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    category = models.ForeignKey("Category", related_name="leads", on_delete= models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30,) # New, Contact, Converted, Unconverted
    orginasation = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

View:

```
class CategoryListView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    template_name = "leads/category_list.html"
    context_object_name = "category_list"

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        user = self.request.user
        #initial query set for entire organisation
        if user.is_organisor:
            queryset = models.Category.objects.filter(orginasation=user.userprofile)
        else:
            queryset = models.Category.objects.filter(orginasation=user.agent.orginasation)
        # count = models.Leads.objects.filter(category = 3).count()
        return queryset
```

template

```
 {% for category in category_list %}
            <tr>
              <td>{{category.name}}/td>
              <td>{{category.count}}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your issue, you should try change from `{{category.count}}` to `{{ category.leads.all.count }}` in your template.

Comment: Is it possible to filter it and show the count for logged in user

Comment: It is possible, but you have to put that filtering in the view's context or create template's custom tag.